# Telerik RadEditor width is increasing

Tags: asp.net, telerik

In my application i am using RadEditor. When i paste anything like images,Text etc. width is increasing. Please tell me how to set width to fixed.

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="radDescription" runat="server" Height="200px" MaxTextLength="3000"
                ContentAreaMode="Div" Width="50%">
```

Can any one help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to set : EnableResize="false" , hope u need that ..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, in that order:

1. upgrade to their latest version
2. use the default ContentAreaMode (Iframe)
3. try increasing the height, it is not enough to fit the
   entire toolbar so this may break some calculations
4. Configure pasting from Word via the [StripFormattingOnPaste property](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/cleaningwordformatting/defaultcs.aspx)